# Update the calendar UI to reflect the new date selected as the first date displayed using the 'gotoDate' function

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4, fullcalendar-scheduler

#### Reduced Test Case

https://jsfiddle.net/ryj1023/5epnoguk/5/

HTML:

```
    <button
           onclick="updateDateRange()"
          >
            Click
          </button>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
    const updateDateRange = () => {
     // calendar.gotoDate(new Date('11-04-2020')); // this will change the view because the date passed in the function isn't currently in view
     calendar.gotoDate(new Date('10-04-2020')); // this will not update the view with the passed in date as the first date in range because it's already in view
     }
     
     var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
     var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          events: [
            {
              id: 'a',
              resourceId: 'a',
              title: 'All Day Event',
              start: '2020-09-01',
            },
            {
              title: 'Long Event',
              start: '2020-09-07',
              end: '2020-09-10',
            },
          ],
          allDaySlot: false,
          displayEventTime: false,
          header: false,
          plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'rrule'],
          defaultView: 'timeGridWeek',
          resourceOrder: 'sort',
          defaultDate: new Date('10-01-2020'),
    
          schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',
    
          views: {
            month: {
              type: 'dayGridMonth',
            },
            week: {
              type: 'resourceTimeline',
              slotLabelFormat: [
                {
                  weekday: 'short',
                  day: 'numeric',
                  month: 'short',
                },
              ],
              resourceLabelText: 'Property',
              duration: {
                days: 14, // getDefaultWeekDuration(start, end)
              },
              dateIncrement: {
                days: 1,
              },
              slotDuration: '24:00:00',
            },
          },
    
          // eventRender: ({ date, el, view }) => {
          // },
          themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
          eventOverlap: false,
          contentHeight: 'auto',
          resourceAreaWidth: '10%',
    
          resources: [{ id: 'a', title: 'Auditorium A' }],
        });
     
     calendar.render();
```

#### Bug Description

I'm trying to update the UI of the calendar using the 'gotoDate' function to so that the date I pass into the function will be reflected as the first date of the range shown. This feature works if the date I'm passing in the function is not already in the range shown in the view. When I select a date that shows in the current range, but is not the first date, the UI does not change.

Comment: This appears to be the expected behaviour - the calendar only bothers to change the date (which involves redrawing it and re-rendering the events, potentially) if the date you want is outside the current rendered area. I didn't write the code but that seems like it's intended to be a timesaver. You could always put in a [feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) to see if you can get an option added to make it work (or even code it yourself as it's open-source). Be aware though it's more likely to be implemented in v5 as that's now superseded v4.

Comment: P.S. your example is a little bit weird, if I may say so - you've got this "week" view, which you specified as "resourceTimeline", but it isn't - you haven't loaded any of the resource or timeline plugins, so it's actually a timeGridWeek view with some custom days, and a strange 24-hour duration which only gives it one slot, and makes it put the date of the first day in the view into the left-side column. It's a little unintuitive...is that the consequence of you trying to make a minimal example or something? I can't see how it would make sense for real use.